# How to start and stop glow each button at specific time according to AM and PM using java script or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on appointment time management and want to glow the button by matching the  system current time to the button value.

For Example:
there is a button with value 3:00 PM. I want to glow this button when the system time reaches to 2:59:59 PM (2 hour 59 minutes and 59 seconds).Make sure the button with value 2:59:59 **AM** not glow when the system date is 2:59:59 **PM**

when time reaches to the 3:14:59 PM stop the glowing button and start Glow up the next button .

Same for the other buttons.

Note: The current code is showing the system current time in the form of digital clock and glowing all the button by using css.

Here is my code:

```js
var $document = $(document);
(function () { 
  var clock = function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    
      date = new Date();    
      hours = date.getHours();
      minutes = date.getMinutes();
      seconds = date.getSeconds();
      dd = (hours >= 12) ? 'pm' : 'am';
      
    hours = (hours > 12) ? (hours - 12) : hours
      
      var timer = setTimeout(clock, 1000);
    
    $('.hours').html('<p>' + Math.floor(hours) + ':</p>');
    $('.minutes').html('<p>' + Math.floor(minutes) + ':</p>');
    $('.seconds').html('<p>' + Math.floor(seconds) + '</p>');
      $('.twelvehr').html('<p>' + dd + '</p>');
  };
  clock();
})();

(function () {
  $document.bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });  
})();
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron);
body {
  background-color: #bcc8d1;font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size:25px;
  line-height:0px;
  color:white;
  font-weight: 100;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.desc {
  width:25%;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:11px;
}
.clock {
  top:30%;
  
  background-color: #3c434c;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:20px;
}
.clock div{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #202731;
  width:25%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

 

.button {
display: inline-block;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 1.42857143;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.button {
-webkit-animation-name: pulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

.button:hover {
cursor:pointer;
-webkit-animation-name: pulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: .8s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
from { color:#ccc;background-color: orange; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #ccc; }
  50% { color:#fff;background-color: red; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 18px #000; }
  to { color:#ccc;background-color: black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px #ccc; }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="2:45 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="3:00 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="3:00 AM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="3:30 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="3:45 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="4:00 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="4:15 PM">
      <input type="button" class="button" href="#" value="4:30 PM">
    <div class="clock" style="margin-left:200px; position:absolute">
      <div class="hours"></div><!--
   --><div class="minutes"></div><!--
    --><div class="seconds"></div><!--
    --><div class="twelvehr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: whilst you've included a snippet, it would also be useful to include a summary of what the current code does, and why you think it's deficient compared to your requirements

Comment: Please read this [mcve] - particularly the minimal part - there's lots of css here that doesn't seem relevant to the issue.   You also don't have a clear *problem statement* - other than "I want it to do this", there appears to be no attempt to make it do that.

Comment: You for sure also need a pad: `function pad(num) { return String("0"+num).slice(-2); }`

Answer (score 2):

First let's create css class for active button:

```
.active{
-webkit-animation-name: pulse;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

Calculate which button should be active:

```
var timeformat = hours + ":" + minutes + " " + dd.toUpperCase();
var buttons = $('.button');
var currentIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  if (buttons[i].value > timeformat) {
    currentIndex = i - 1;
    break;
  };
}
```

Add and remove active class only when it changes:

```
if (currentIndex != tempIndex) {
   $(buttons[currentIndex]).addClass("active");
   $(buttons[tempIndex]).removeClass("active");
   tempIndex = currentIndex; //global var store last active index start with -1
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/t6xeo9g4/), hope it helps!

Comment: Two things are not working..1st if the clock reaches at 5:20 AM the button with value 5:20 PM is starting to glow.

Comment: 2nd when the time reaches equal to the last button value the first button is start glowing.

Comment: 1st problem: you will need to convert "timeformat" and "buttons[i].value" to something you want exactly then compare it, in your case, I suggest converting it to minutes. 2nd prolem: let "currentIndex" start with "buttons.length - 1", hope it helps!

Comment: Check this fiddle.jshell.net/a0una68w, hope it helps!

Comment: when we set the our operating system time in AM format then AM values are glowing but when I set the operating system time to PM format the PM values are not glowing..

Comment: It's because "currentminutes" is from "new Date()" not from your clock in view. So changing AM<->PM make the system misunderstand. To fix it, you will need to recalculate "currentminutes" in other ways.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125051/discussion-between-waqas-adil-and-k-angel7).